# HTML & CSS : How delete <td> tag from print view

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a table :

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>#</td>.
     <td>Nmae</td>
     <td class="notforprint">Class</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>.
     <td>Jhon</td>
     <td class="notforprint">A</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
     <td>2</td>.
     <td>Tom</td>
     <td class="notforprint">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I create css style to hide  tag :

```
<style>
    @media print {
        .notforprint{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
</style>
```

and it is works fine.

but the  tags take thier space in view therefor I want to delete those  in print view.

is that possible?

Comment: `display: none;`

Comment: visibility: hidden still keeps the space the element would take up if it were visible - you just can't see it. display: none means it doesn't get rendered so no space taken up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable the display with:

```css
.notforprint
{
display: none;
}
```